# Reactive JS (RxJs) Group by key

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a data stream with e.g. the following values:

```
Observable.of(
    [{time: 1000, a: 100},
    {time: 1000, b: 100},
    {time: 2000, a: 200}]
);
```

And need to merge the values based on `time` to get:

```
[{time: 1000, a: 100, b: 100},
{time: 2000, a: 200}]
```

I can use `map` and `reduce` but then I end up with a single map that I have to split somehow again. Is there a more straight forward way in RxJs?

Comment: Do you need to use RxJs for this? If so, then do you want to emit the current aggregate for each emit or wait for completion? Can you show what you already tried with `map` and `reduce` and the result that you didn't like.

Comment: Also, would it sum values with the same key?

Comment: For values with the same key I'm fine with choosing a "random" one, since I do not expect this. 

I'm using RxJs since I get the data as an Observable form the Angular HttpClient.

My actual structure is slightly different than in the question, but I covered that in the answer below. Finding the "groupBy" function was the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do an array `reduce` inside of a `map` operator. Might be a bit clearer than the `groupBy` and `flatMap`. This is more of a data mapping issue than an rxjs issue.

```js
Rx.Observable.of(
 [{time: 1000, a: 100},
   {time: 1000, b: 100},
   {time: 2000, a: 200}]
).map(data => {
  return data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(x => x.time === cur.time);
    if (index >= 0) {
      acc[index] = { ...acc[index], ...cur };
    } else {
      acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
})
.subscribe(x => { console.log('result', x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this in the end:

```
    Observable.of(
      [{time: 1000, channelKey: 'a', value: 100},
        {time: 1000, channelKey: 'b',value: 100},
        {time: 2000,  channelKey: 'a', value: 200}]
    )
    .flatMap<any[], any>(x => x)
    .groupBy(v => Math.floor(v.time.getTime() / 1000), v => {
        return {[v.channelKey]: v.value}
    })
    .flatMap((group$) => group$.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(cur, acc), {time: group$.key}))
    .toArray()
    .subscribe((v) => {
        console.log("Value: ", v)
    })
```